# Add :hover to decendent

Tags: html, css

How do I add a hover to the following:

```
 table.pvtTable tr th, table.pvtTable tr th
```

I want it added to the final "th" element.

If I do:

```
 table.pvtTable tr th, table.pvtTable tr th:hover
```

everything here is applied by default.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you have the same selector twice in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work for the last `th`  :

```
table.pvtTable tr th:last-child
```

And the same element with `:hover` selector :

```
 table.pvtTable tr th:last-child:hover
```

Comment: surely it should be `table.pvtTable tr th:last-child:hover`

Comment: @user3529729:If you want it to work on all browsers you should make a javascript fall back to style your last `th`.

Comment: @Notulysses, It's not my post and I added this info just in case somebody finds it useful.